# Find variable k in the angle between 2 vectors

Tags: vectors

> $A$ is the point $(3, -3, 0)$, $B$ is the point $(2, -3, 1)$ and $C$ is $(4,k,0)$.
>
> (a) Express $\vec{BA}$ and $\vec{BC}$ in the component form.
>
> (b) Show
> that angle $\angle ABC = \frac{3}{\sqrt{2(k^2 + 6x + 14)}}$.
>
> (c) If $\angle ABC > 30^\circ$, find the possible values for $k$.

(a) $$\vec{BA} = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\vec{BC} = \begin{bmatrix}2\\k+3\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$

(b) $$\cos \angle ABC = \frac{(-1)(2) + (0)(k+3) + 1(-1)}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{4 + k^2 + 6k + 9 + 1}} $$

=>$$\cos \angle ABC = \frac{-3}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{k^2 + 6k + 14}} $$

I am not sure how to progress from here.

Comment: For one the last component of $BC$ is wrong.

Comment: @travis updated the question

Answer (score 0):

This problem is threefold. To begin, let us find the vector from point $B(2,-3,1)$ to point $A(3,-3,0)$. Let us name this vector $\vec{\mathbf u}$.
$$\vec{\mathbf u}=\langle3-2,-3+3,0-1\rangle=\langle1,0,-1\rangle\tag a$$
Now, let us find the vector from point $B(2,-3,1)$ to point $C(4,k,0)$. Let us name this vector $\vec{\mathbf v}$.
$$\vec{\mathbf v}=\langle4-2,k+3,0-1\rangle=\langle2,k+3,-1\rangle\tag a$$
Let us find the magnitude of $\vec{\mathbf u}$.
$$\lVert\vec{\mathbf u}\rVert=\sqrt{(1)^2+(0)^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt{2}$$
Let us find the magnitude of $\vec{\mathbf v}$.
$$\lVert\vec{\mathbf v}\rVert=\sqrt{(2)^2+(k+3)^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt{4+k^2+6k+9+1}=\sqrt{k^2+6k+14}$$
Let us find the angle between these two vectors $\theta$, which is $\angle ABC$.
$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{\vec{\mathbf u}\cdot\vec{\mathbf v}}{\lVert\vec{\mathbf u}\rVert\lVert\vec{\mathbf v}\rVert}=\frac{(1)(2)+(0)(k+3)+(-1)(-1)}{\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{k^2+6k+14}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2k^2+12k+28}}$$
Now, let us isolate $\theta$.
$$\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2k^2+12k+28}}\right)\tag b$$
Since the angle $\theta$ between the two vectors is greater than $30$ degrees, we can solve for $k$ with an inequality. Additionally, the angle between the two vectors is not only greater than $30$ degrees but also less than $90$ degrees because $\vec{\mathbf u}\cdot\vec{\mathbf v}=3\gt0$ [[1](http://math.la.asu.edu/%7Esurgent/mat272/dotcross.pdf)].
$$\arccos\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2k^2+12k+28}}\right)\gt\frac{\pi}{6}\implies-1\le\frac{3}{\sqrt{2k^2+12k+28}}\lt\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\le1$$
The expression containing $k$ must be within the domain of the arccosine function. Notice that the direction of the inequality symbol between the expression and $\pi/6$ was reversed. We can simplify this. The expression that is under the radicand is positive for any real number $k$.
$$-1\le\frac{3}{\sqrt{2k^2+12k+28}}\lt\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\implies-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\le\frac{6}{\sqrt{6k^2+36k+84}}\lt1$$
The expression in the middle is positive for any real number $k$. Square each expression.
$$0\lt\frac{6}{k^2+6k+14}\lt1$$
We know that the rational expression in the middle is less than $1$ if the numerator $6$ is less than the denominator $k^2+6k+14$, which is positive for any real number $k$.
$$6\lt k^2+6k+14\implies0\lt k^2+6k+8$$
Solving the inequality for $k$, we will find the values of $k$ that have the angle between vectors $\vec{\mathbf u}$ and $\vec{\mathbf v}$ greater than $30$ degrees but less than $90$ degrees. We can utilize the quadratic formula on the quadratic equation $k^2+6k+8=0$ with $a=1$, $b=6$, and $c=8$.
$$k=\frac{-(6)\pm\sqrt{(6)^2-4(1)(8)}}{2(1)}=\frac{-6\pm2}{2}=-3\pm1$$
This gives us two different values of $k$. We have $k=-3-1=-4$ and $k=-3+1=-2$. We can see that $k^2+6k+8$ is positive (greater than zero) everywhere but between and including these two values of $k$ because $a$ is positive. This is because $a=1\gt0$ has the graph of $y=x^2+6x+8$ (a parabola) open upwards [[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function)]. This places values of $x^2+6x+8$ above the $x$-axis for $x\in(-\infty,-4)\cup(-2,\infty)$, giving us two open intervals for $k$. Thus, we have our values of $k$ now and have finished solving the problem in its entirety. Indeed, WolframAlpha confirms our results [[3](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20arccos%283%2Fsqrt%282x%5E2%2B12x%2B28%29%29%20greater%20than%20%CF%80%2F6.)].
$$k\in(-\infty,-4)\cup(-2,\infty)\tag c$$